# Discord modal in DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, dsharp+

In my discord bot it is necessary to implement the Modals system. Having searched for information on this matter, I realized that in the DSharpPlus library there is no possibility to use modal. As a result, I found the XeroxDev.DSharpPlus.ModalCommands library. After reading its instructions, I still didn’t understand how to work with it and got stuck at the stage of sending the modal to the user.

```
               DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder modal = ModalBuilder.Create("test_modal")
                    .WithTitle("Test Modal Title")
                    .AddComponents(new TextInputComponent("TextImput1", "ti1", "..."));
                await e.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.UpdateMessage, modal);
```

When running the code, the console reports an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSharpPlus supports [modal windows](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder.html), the code will be almost identical to XeroxDev

Based on the code you posted, you need to change the response type to the modal window

```
DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder modal = ModalBuilder.Create("test_modal")
                    .WithTitle("Test Modal Title")
                    .AddComponents(new TextInputComponent("TextImput1", "ti1", "..."));
await e.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.Modal, modal);
```

To get the user's response, you need to subscribe to the ModalSubmitted event and send a response to discord that everything is fine

```
DiscordClient.ModalSubmitted += Discord_ModalSubmitted;

public static async Task Discord_ModalSubmitted(DiscordClient sender, ModalSubmitEventArgs e)
{
    await e.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate);
}
```

Well, to get data from the window, we wait for the user’s response and take the necessary data from the returned dictionary

```
DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder modal = ModalBuilder.Create("test_modal")
                            .WithTitle("Test Modal Title")
                            .AddComponents(new TextInputComponent("TextImput1", "ti1", "..."));
await e.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.Modal, modal);
                    
var response = await e.Client.GetInteractivity().WaitForModalAsync("test_modal");                                             
    
string TextInput1 = response.Result.Values["ti1"];
```